# what is the difference between "like" and "as"?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage

what is the difference between "like" and "as"?

Do people use these in similar situations?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this link and if you still find them confusing, consider editing your question to address a particular issue: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/and

Comment: ***As*** a relatively competent native speaker, I can use "as" to start this sentence with the clear implication that I really ***am*** a competent speaker. If I were to use ***like*** instead (a much less common phrasing for this particular context) that would mean that I was simply *acting in the same way* as a competent speaker, with the strong implication that I wasn't one really. So, @fluffy, I'm afraid your link is potentially misleading where it says ***Like, as if** and **as though** can all be used to make comparisons. There is no difference in meaning among the 3 forms*.

Comment: Which context you are talking about? They might be used interchangeably and they are all different as well! *He's like my brother  will look awkward if said -He's as my brother!*

Comment: I disagree that this question is too broad and should be closed. It is obvious that it refers to the situations where both "like" and "as" are used: comparison and similarity. Other usages of the two words are not relevant. Luckily, the accepted answer understood that and went straight to the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Like* and *as* are used with a comparable meaning in two situations.

#### Comparison

When I compare two things that are *equal* in some way, I use *as*...*as*...

> My brother is *as* tall *as* my father.
>   John is *as* rich *as* Paul.

This means that my brother and my father have the same height, and that Paul and John have the same amount of money.

When I compare two things that are *similar* in some way, I use *like*.

> My brother is tall, *like* my father.
>   John is rich *like* Paul.

This means that both my father and my brother are tall, taller than average, but they are not necessarily the same height. Also, John and Paul both have more money than most people, but one can still have more than the other.

In these sentences, I just express that they both share a property (being tall, or being rich), but they do not have to have the property to the same extent.

#### Simile

If I do something in a way *similar* to the way someone else would do it, or if I describe that something has a property in a similar way some other object does, I use *like*.

> He handled the situation like a gentleman.
>   This vehicle has four wheels, like most cars.

I am not saying that *he* actually *is* (always) a gentlemen, but the way he handled this situation was the way a gentleman would handle it, so his behaviour was similar to that of  gentleman.
This vehicle may not be an actual car, but it is *like* a car in the sense that it has four wheels.

Now, if I do something because *I am* a certain kind of person, or I describe that something has a certain property because *it is* a certain kind of abject, I use *as*.

> As a gentleman, he handled the situation very well.
>   As a car, this vehicle has to have four wheels.

Because he is a gentleman, he handled the situation well; since the vehicle *is* a car, I expect it to have four wheels.

You can use *being* to replace *as* in these sentences to convey the same meaning:

> Being a gentleman, he handled the situation very well.
>   Being a car, this vehicle has to have four wheels.

---

Note that I left out other uses of *like* and *as*, where they are not used in similar ways. I can say *as soon as possible*, for instance, but there is no similar way to convey a similar meaning using *like*. In the same way, I can use *like* as a verb, but that is not really relevant in this case.